# Limit jQuery.ajaxSetup scope to inside a specific object only

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, scope

This might be strange, but what I am looking for is how would I make the scope of `jQuery.ajaxSetup()` inside a specific object only. Let me give you an example, I have two objects `obj_1` and `obj_2`. I want to write ajaxSetup in such a way that all my ajax calls inside an object will use one set of params and all my calls in second object will use other set of params.

Eg

```
var obj_1 = {

    my_func : function(){

        $.ajax({
            success : function(){
                // do something
                // all ajax calls in this object should use one set of params (type,dataType,headers etc)
            }
        })

    }

};

var obj_2 = {

    my_func : function(){

        $.ajax({
            success : function(){
                // do something
                // all ajax calls in this object should use different params (type,dataType,headers etc)
            }
        })

    }

};
```

I want to do this so that I don't have to write all params in every ajax call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to create a function for use by the object and have it set the parameters when doing the ajax call. The object uses that function rather than calling `ajax` directly. E.g., a simple wrapper function.

Alternately, you could have a `standardParams` property on each object that you reuse, perhaps mixing in the params that are specific to the call. Something like:

```
var obj_x = {
    standardParams: {
        // These are the params that don't vary
        dataType: "json" // Or whatever
    },

    your_func: function() {
        $.ajax($.extend({}, this.standardParams, {
            // These are the params that vary
            success: function() { ... }
        }));
    }
};
```

(Note the use of `jQuery.extend` to mix the per-call and standard params.)

Or of course, you could use a combination of the two (a wrapper function, which uses a `standardParams` property under the covers).

Comment: +1 However, isn't there a way where I can directly write $.ajax without passing anything to it ? this solution is perfect for me, but other newbie coders might find it hard to maintain. i want to make it as simple as possible.

Comment: @atif089: Using a wrapper function is very, very simple; newbie coders shouldn't have any trouble with it. But no, `ajaxSetup` is global to jQuery as a whole. If it had a mechanism for letting you do this in a non-global way, the most likely scenario would be that it would return a function reference and you'd use that reference for calls instead of using `ajax` directly -- because it was using a wrapper function. :-)